# adb install doesn't stop when adb klill-server has been started

Tags: android, adb, adt

This is my first post here, so first of all, hello everybody!

I am not sure if it is bug or a feature:) but I have noticed that when you will run adb install with no device connected, it firstly starts adb daemon (if was not currently running), and then wait for the device. After that, when you open new window and run adb kill-server, adb install command will not stop, but shows protocol fault and then restart adb daemon again.
There is no other way of stopping this, than killing the process (for example using ctrl+c).

[Screenshot](http://s7.postimg.org/qgycc4ytn/screenshot.png)

I have also noticed that other commands like adb shell, adb devices, adb wait-for-device doesn't act like adb install - stop when adb kill-server will be lunched.

My version of ADB is 1.0.31
I have tested this issue on Linux and Windows, and both works the same.

Please let me know, what do you think about it.

Best Regards,
Pawel